# How to make Listview Expandable in Xamarin Form

Tags: visual-studio, listview, xamarin.forms

i am new to **Xamarin Form**.
I was given a task to make `Listview` expendable. I am trying for a week but I couldn't do it.
Please if anyone has an idea that how to do it then let me know.
Thanks

Comment: here are several solutions https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/33975/how-to-implement-expandable-collapsible-listview-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: What you want seems like a kind of Accordion View. [This blog](https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.com.br/2016/10/build-accordion-view-in-xamarinforms.html) suggest a solution. I've implemented it like a ObservableCollection inherited class with title informations and one private list<T> that removes (collapse) and adds (expand) the itens, using it in a grouped ListView. It's more like a C# instead of Xamarin.Forms solution, actually. It works very well to me.